# ember-data 1.0 relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using a rest adapter with ember-data 1.0 and ember.js 1.0

given these models:

```
App.Customer  = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    state: DS.belongsTo("State")
});


App.State  = DS.Model.extend({
   region: DS.attr('string'),
   state: DS.attr('string'),
   stateName: DS.attr('string'),
   customers: DS.hasMany("Customer")
});
```

when I go to /#/states, I get this json response

```
{
  "states": [
 {
  "region": "West",
  "state": "AZ",
  "stateName": "Arizona",
  "id": "0x0000000000000324",
  "customers": [
    "0x00000000000001e5"
  ]
},
{
  "region": "West",
  "state": "CA",
  "stateName": "California",
  "id": "0x0000000000000325",
  "customers": [
    "0x00000000000001c0",
    "0x00000000000001c4",
    "0x00000000000001d4"
  ]
 }
]

"customers" : [
 {
 }
 ]
}
```

Now, I have a couple of questions

1) What should I put in the Customers part ? A complete list of all the customers, or just a list of the customers that are specified in the state list ?

2) what data should I send back if I visit /#/customers ?

3) If I were to edit a customer. would I set it up so that the lookup/combo makes a separate request to the server ?

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  In your original JSON the `customers` array should only contain customers who are present in the state list.

2)  This depends on your app.  Generally you would want `/customers` to return all customers.  Or maybe a paginated collection of customers.  Or maybe only customers that the currently logged in user is allowed to see.  Etc...

3) When you edit a customer Ember should already have the customer data loaded, so no additional lookup request should be required.

Comment: 1) + 2) : thanks
3) : it was the state that I was looking up. I was wondering if it were possible to use the model for the state controller, or set up a new collection in the customer controller:

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
          this._super(controller, model);
      this.controllerFor('state').set('content', this.store.find('state'));
  },